# Cannot use addEventListener Last parameter (event capturing)

Tags: javascript

I am having an onclick event on a button.

```
    <button id="myButton">Click me</button>

var item = document.getElementById("myButton");
myButton.addEventListener("click", "myFunction", false);//using event bubbling

function myFunction(){
alert("Hello World");
}
```

The issue is the event is not being fired if I use the last paramenter of addEventListener.
This [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/tq83y9h7/) working Example.
THIS [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/maxspan/ydmc06xg/) not Working Example.

Can anybody explain why. Is the last parameter of addEventListener is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have passed myFunction in Quatation. instead it should be `myButton.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);`

try following:

```
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>

var item = document.getElementById("myButton");
myButton.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);//using event bubbling

function myFunction(){
alert("Hello World");
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/71jtLjdr/) is working fiddle with three arguments.

**NOTE**: First fiddle was working because you were using anonymous function there.